# Почему не работают сокеты? (Android)

Tags: java, android

При попытке создания сокета:

```
sock = new Socket("localhost", 4000);
```

вываливается исключение 'EPERM (Operation not permitted)'. Разрешение для интернета создал:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: моя любимая ссылка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный StackTrace. В нём скорее всего будет исключение  `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, про которое на SO спрашивали уже десятки раз.